# magento Create link dynamically in customer account navigation based on customer group

Tags: magento, navigation

> how to adding new customer account navigation link based on customer
>   group in magento. I am using magento-1.8

Comment: We generally do it from xml. But here you need to check from which customer group he belongs. So try to edit navigation.phtml file under customer/account folder. Try to add a condition and add your link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?